# Selenium is unable to locate element(id)

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

SO I am trying to make an automation that logs into my account. This is my code rn:

```
    import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

def get_all_results(Username, password):
    url = "https://portail.sainteanne.ca/pluriportail/fr/MainExterne.srf?P=LoginReq"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(url)

    Username_sbox = browser.find_element_by_id("NomLogin")
    Username_sbox.send_keys(Username)
    Username_sbox.submit()

    Pass_sbox = browser.find_element_by_id("MotPasse")
    Pass_sbox.send_keys(password)
    Pass_sbox.submit()

    browser.close()

get_all_results("random_username123232", "random_password1234")
```

And this is the result I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\CSA\OneDrive - College Sainte-Anne\Programming\PYTHON\Learning\WS\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 18, in <module>
    get_all_results("random_username123232", "random_password1234") 
  File "c:\Users\CSA\OneDrive - College Sainte-Anne\Programming\PYTHON\Learning\WS\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 8, in get_all_results
    Username_sbox = browser.find_element_by_id("NomLogin")
  File "C:\Users\CSA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\CSA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\CSA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\CSA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: **Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="NomLogin"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)**
```

I just started to automate with browsers and i am confused. Pls help. Thanks :).

Comment: you can find the url from code. https://portail.sainteanne.ca/pluriportail/fr/MainExterne.srf?P=LoginReq

Comment: Last time I did anything with selenium I just used xpath for everything...  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to let the browser load before letting selenium run any function :

```
 import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

 url = "url.of.the.website.com"
 browser = webdriver.Chrome()
 browser.get(url)

 browser.implicitly_wait(10)  # <--- THIS IS THE FUNCTION I WAS LOOKING FOR

 #...Enter username.... blablabla and DONE!
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to place waits in your code to help finding elements.  Sometimes an element is being looked for before the page is done loading the element which will cause an "element not found" error.  Add this to your code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Username_sbox = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "NomLogin"))

Pass_sbox = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "MotPasse"))
```

This will give the browser time to load before throwing the error that it can't find the element.

More information on waits can be found here:  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html